# Why do salts for hashing passwords need to be globally unique, not just system/site-unique?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking, password-policy, salt

I was reading an answer by Terry Chia to [another question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41617/do-salts-have-to-be-random-or-just-unique-and-unknown) about the requirements for a salt, in which he/she (among others) specified that salts need to be globally unique, but don't go into any detail on why.  This was defined as "not only unique in the context of your database, but unique in the context of every single database out there".  For example, I have been using an email address as a salt for my experiment-y sandbox website/database.  These could certainly be being used as salts on other websites.

It doesn't make sense to me because, as I understand it, the purpose of the salt is to ensure that "cracking multiple compromised password hashes together should be no easier than cracking each one of them separately" (Ilmari Karonen, further down on the same post).  Unless I'm mistaken, this constraint is satisfied as long as my salts are unique within my database.

I am further confused because generating globally unique salts sounds impossible for me to control.  How am I supposed to be able to guarantee that none of my salts have ever been used on someone else's site, with the millions of sites out there?  To be fair, I haven't looked into how to generate random salts yet; maybe the idea is that they are created from a large enough pool that even considering the number of sites out there, duplicate salts generated for separate databases is very unlikely?

I am definitely biased towards using an email address as my salt, since it's one less small step of work, but given the number of people who seem to disagree with this approach, I recognize that I am probably wrong.  And besides, I want to know more about why I'm wrong because it doesn't make sense yet.

Comment: It sounds like he misspoke or you misunderstood him. A "pepper" is globally unique, whereas a salt is unique for each hash. As for using an email as a salt... just look at the issue with router default names (since router ESSIDs are used as WPA2 salts). The issue is that someone could precompute a rainbow table just by knowing your email, long before they ever break into your database.

Comment: @Baal-zebub you are interpreting "globally unique" oddly. Peppers are "globally applied" within the scope. The linked answers stated that salts should be random, unguessable, and therefore 'unique' from any other salt on any database, i.e. "unique globally"

Comment: That's why I said the OP might have misunderstood him. It could easily be that I got the English wrong. To me I would think of there being globally unique, or there being individually unique. But anyway that confusion from me is why I commented instead of answered. :)

Comment: salts should be random, you should not use anything easily guessable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The goal of salting is *resistance to precomputation*.

While you can't *guarantee* that a salt is globally unique, you can (just as you said) generate salts of sufficient size as to make it infeasible to generate a [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) in advance (making them "unique enough").

More generally, if you're asking about how to create a salt, it sounds like you're rolling your own hashing method, which may be educational but is not generally recommended.

Instead, use an existing hash (such as PBDKF2 or bcrypt) (or even better, as CBHacking rightly suggests in the comments, scrypt or Argon2). Not only will you automatically inherit their existing salting methods (which are quite sufficient), but your experimentation will be aligned with password storage best practices ... which would probably be better practice.

**Update 2018-04-03**: Steve Thomas (sc00bz) makes a good point [here](https://twitter.com/Sc00bzT/status/981166657899978758) that Argon2 and scrypt are actually worse for the defender when used at speeds generally considered to be compatible with authentication at scale (<0.1 seconds), while being better for the defender for speeds compatible with encryption of individual files (1 to 5 seconds). (This means that the gap from 0.1 seconds to 1 second is probably interesting, and bears testing for your specific environment). In other words, his assertion is that if you try to tune Argon2 or scrypt to <0.1s speeds, the results are less resistant to cracking than bcrypt is at those speeds.

In the same thread, Aaron Toponce also [makes a great suggestion](https://twitter.com/AaronToponce/status/981169902382821383) for working around bcrypt's length (72 characters max) and pre-hashing limitations, by using `bcrypt(base64(sha-256(password)))`. (See also Thomas Pornin's similar answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/61602/6203)). The reason that the base64 is needed [is also interesting](https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2015/03/security-issue-combining-bcrypt-with.html) - don't leave it out.

So if your use case is scaleable, cracking-resistant authentication with a fast authentication experience, `bcrypt(base64(sha-256(password)))` is probably a good approach. (And you'll need to adjust bcrypt's work factor to the highest value that fits within your authentication speed window). If your users can tolerate waiting a second or more to authenticate, Argon2i or scrypt may be better. And note that relative performance will shift over time, as hardware capabilities improve - so increasing the bcrypt work factor every X months for new hashes (as Dropbox does) would allow the approach to adapt to future capabilities over time.

**Update 2019-09-01** It turns out that wrapping a faster hash in a slower hash without salting/peppering that faster hash first is dangerous, because fast uncracked unsalted hashes from another source (such as another leak) can be tested in bulk against the wrapped hashes *without having to crack those faster hashes first*. The faster hashes can then be attacked in a separate job at a much higher rate. So my advice above should be updated to  `bcrypt(base64(sha256(password.salt)))`.

Comment: scrypt (or the new argon2, which was specifically designed and tested for this purpose and is the winner of a three-year competition) are better choices than PBKDF2 or bcrypt. While bcrypt's memory requirement is higher than PBKDF2's, it's not tunable and is still very low by modern standards; parallelizing it still isn't that hard. The newer algorithms are fully tunable.

Comment: Bcrypt is tunable. It has "cost factors" that let you tune the CPU trade-off. It's not as versatile as argon2 which has separate memory and CPU cost options.

Comment: @CBHacking, while I agree that argon2 and scrypt are superior, I also believe that PBKDF2 and bcrypt are more widespread, and more likely to be accessible to this questioner and their platform.

Comment: @forest I never said it wasn't, I said the newer ones are *fully* tunable, and that bcrypt's memory usage isn't high enough (implying, correctly, that it isn't tunable in that regard).

Comment: `While bcrypt's memory requirement is higher than PBKDF2's, it's not tunable and is still very low by modern standards` is what I saw. Doesn't matter though, I get your point.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams, I'm sure somebody out there has a counterexample but I can't think of a single platform I've seen (and I've seen many) that had a bcrypt implementation but not either scrypt or argon2; they were very widely ported after release. In any case, it is irresponsible to simply assume the questioner couldn't access the newer algorithms, and only tell them about the outdated ones.

Comment: @forest the antecedent of "it" in that sentence is obviously the memory cost. The rest of the sentence doesn't even make sense otherwise.

Comment: @CBHacking, I appreciate your perspective. I think that "irresponsible" is a bit strong, given the vast gap that exists between "roll your own crypto" and bcrypt/PBKDF2/Argon2/scrypt. bcrypt and PBKDF2 are very well-baked and have been tested in the field for years, which is not an uncommon standard for crypto-related functions. The assertion that Argon2 and scrypt are just as accessible as bcrypt and PBKDF2 is harder when legacy/older systems are in play. I stand by my original recommendation, while at the same time also welcoming scrypt (of which I am a long-time fan), and Argon2.

Comment: bcrypt and PBKDF2 are not outdated, they are simply suboptimal.

Comment: An interesting March 2018 Purdue economic analysis that demonstrates the superiority of memory-hard functions, and recommends deprecating PBKDF2 and bcrypt: (cc @CBHacking): https://csdl.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/sp/2018/4353/00/435301a035.pdf

Answer (score 4):

There is no advantage in using the e-mail address instead of generating a random value. You have to store it anyway like the random salt, otherwise the user can never change the e-mail address.

The global uniqueness is not a requirement, you don't need to guarantee the uniqueness, but the more globally unique the salts are, the better. The possible combinations for a 128-bit salt (BCrypt) are 3E38. Even if you generate 1000 salts/sec one would expect about 6E8 years to wait for a 50% chance of a duplicate.

As Royce already mentioned, todays algorithms already generate the salt for you, and store it plaintext in the resulting hash-string, so there is no need for special handling in the database (just 1 field for the hash).

When using email addresses, an attacker could pre calculate rainbow tables for certain emails of interest.

While the disadvantages are not fatal in practise, there are simply no advantages, so why would you choose a more complicate and unsafer method to generate the salt? Use a modern password hash function and you are good.

Comment: Good point about people needing to change the email address later.  I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

This topic becomes much clearer if instead of saying that salts "need" to be globally unique, we observe instead that optimal security is achieved if they are.

Consider the following simplistic attack model: an attacker obtains `n` password entries, and they have the resources to make `m` tests in total.  Now consider the extreme cases:

- If the passwords are unsalted (or all have the same salt), then each of the `m` computations can be checked against all `n` entries.  Which means they get to test `m * n` user/password hypotheses.
- If all the passwords are salted with unique salts, then each of the `m` computations can only be checked against 1 entry.   Which means they only get to test `m` user/password hypotheses.

If some but not all salts are duplicates, the attacker gets something in between, proportional to the number of distinct salts.  But this doesn't mean that salting fails catastrophically on salt duplication, but rather that its effectiveness degrades linearly.

Since sufficiently large random salts are generally easy to implement and achieve global uniqueness with all but negligible chance against, there's really very little reason not to go that way.

Random salts have another important property, which [martinstoeckli's answer to the question you link](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/41627/112339) points out: the attacker cannot predict ahead of time what salts you will use.  Your proposal to use email addresses fails that criterion.

Answer (score 0):

The salt hides the fact that two people use the same passwords. That has a minor effect - cracking one persons password doesn’t give me another password for free. There is a big effect - an attacker can’t find weak passwords. And another big effect - an attacker can’t use a hard drive full of pre-calculated hashes.

If everyone used the same salt these effects would all disappear. But if say ten users of different sites use the same salt, matching hashes will be rare even with bad passwords. So what would happen is that once in a while two people have the same hash and password and an attacker could think the password is weak. On a site with a million users and no salt there would be thousands with the same hash because of weak passwords, not two with the same hash once in a while.

PS. Usually finding matching hashes allows an attacker to conclude that passwords are weak. Different users will only have the same password if it is weak. However, if *my* password produces the same hash on two sites using the same salt, that will happen if I use the same extraordinarily safe password on two sites, so it doesn’t mean at all my password is easy to crack.