# Which part of this encoded Argon2 hash is the salt?

Tags: hash, salt, argon2

I was reading the post [Is it safe/wise to store a salt in the same field as the hashed password?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183083/is-it-safe-wise-to-store-a-salt-in-the-same-field-as-the-hashed-password):

> `$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=3,p=1$YOtX2//7NoD/owm8RZ8llw==$fPn4sPgkFAuBJo3M3UzcGss3dJysxLJdPdvojRF20ZE=`
>
> My understanding is that everything prior to `p=` are parameters, **the body of the `p=` is the salt**, and the last part is the hashed password."

I do not understand the highlighted part. I thought`$` slices variant, version, parameters, salt and hash, so that:

- p (parallelism parameter) = `1`
- salt = `YOtX2//7NoD/owm8RZ8llw==`
- hash = `fPn4sPgkFAuBJo3M3UzcGss3dJysxLJdPdvojRF20ZE=`

Am I correct in identifying salt and hash here?

Comment: I hope you are asking this out of curiousity and not because you actually want to parse the output of some Argon2 tool.

Comment: @MechMK1 : Thanks for replying, Sir. I was just trying to learn how to store passwords, learned that Argon2 is nice through a series of posts, but, got stuck in this particular question(post) over identifying salt, hence asked a question here. Everything is clear now...until I stuck again.

Comment: I'm glad that you are asking questions, but my point was that if you are building a system that uses Argon2, you should not parse those things yourself. Instead, use a pre-built library that does all these things for you.

Comment: @MechMK1 Following your advice, I searched for a library. And, now, I  am now using `argon2-cffi`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=3,p=1$YOtX2//7NoD/owm8RZ8llw==$fPn4sPgkFAuBJo3M3UzcGss3dJysxLJdPdvojRF20ZE=`

- `argon2{i}` three types i,d,id

  - **Argon2d** is faster and uses data-depending memory access. Data dependency immediately enables side-channel. This is suitable for cryptocurrencies and applications with no threats from side-channel attacks.
- **Argon2i** uses data-independent memory access and this is preferred for password hashing and password-based key derivations.
- **Argon2id** In the first half of the first iteration works as Argon2i and the rest works as the Argon2d. This enables both side-channel protection and time-memory trade-off.

  And if you don't know the difference or you consider side-channel attacks as viable threats use [Argon2id](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-argon2-03#section-3.1).

  Better advice `Use Argon2id unless you know you have a good reason to use any other mode` by [MechMK1](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/163495/mechmk1)
- `v=19` - `v` for version, here version is 19
- `m=65536` - `m` is the integer representing the variable memory cost,  in kibibytes here 65536 kibibytes.
- `t` - is the integer representing the variable timing cost in linear iteration, here 3.
- `p=1` - `p` is the parallelization mechanism to control the amount of parellization
- salt - here `YOtX2//7NoD/owm8RZ8llw==`
- digest - here `fPn4sPgkFAuBJo3M3UzcGss3dJysxLJdPdvojRF20ZE=`

Split with `$` sign, the last token is the digest and the one before the last token is the salt.

---

Note: Argon2 is a key derivation function that was selected as the winner of the Password Hashing Competition in July 2015. The Specs paper;

- [Argon2: the memory-hard function for password hashing and other
  applications](https://password-hashing.net/argon2-specs.pdf)

Comment: I know the official description is "If you don't know the difference, use Argon2id", but I think a better description is "Use Argon2id unless you *know* you have a good reason to use any other mode".

Comment: What encoding is shown for salt and digest? Base64? Is there a recommended encoding?